# How to use function crop(x, y, ...) from raster package so that the output is information about y (raster) contained in x (shapefile, extent object)

Tags: r, r-raster, rgdal, rgeo-shapefile

I am kind of new to R and especially to working with GIS in R, so I hope I explain this right.

I want to get the function crop (x,y...) from package raster to merge/overlay (not sure what's the correct expression to use) a raster file with a shapefile. Essentially, the shapefile is a 5 x 5 km grid of Sweden and the raster is a landuse raster of Sweden. By using the crop function I want to get a result which, for each 5x5 km square from the shapefile, gives information extracted from the raster file about the type of landuse in each square.

However, when I use crop and then write.csv from what I cropped 'crop (landuse, ekrut)" (see code below), I basically just get the ekrut (shapefile) as output csv file, there are no columns added of the landuse raster indicating which square has which land use class.

I am sorry but I cannot share the actual shapefile here, if it will make a difference somehow, the landuse data can be downloaded from here: 
http://gpt.vic-metria.nu/data/land/NMD/NMD2018_basskikt_ogeneraliserad_Sverige_v1_0.zip

## Here's what I tried to do so far

```
library (raster)
library (rgdal)
library (sp)
```

this is the coordinate system/projection for the GIS file. Each coordinate 
system has an epsg code (http://spatialreference.org/).

```
sweref.def <- "+init=epsg:3006" 

# read in shapefile
ekrut <- readOGR (dsn   = "//storage-al.slu.se/student$/nilc0001/Desktop/Nina/Ekrut", 
                  layer = "ekrut_5x5_flat", 
                  p4s   = sweref.def) 

ekrut
# class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
# features    : 19192 
# extent      : 266333, 921700, 6131565, 7675329  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +init=epsg:3006 +proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
# variables   : 7
# names       :    AREA, PERIMETER,  GGD_, GGD_ID,     BK, Bk_num, BK_flat 
# min values  : 2.5e+07,     20000,     2,      0, 10A 0f, 012 77,   10A0f 
# max values  : 2.5e+07,     20000, 19208,  19230,  9J 9d, 329 48,    9J9d 

#read in raster
landuse <- raster ("nmd2018bas_ogeneraliserad_v1_0.tif")

landuse

# class       : RasterLayer 
# dimensions  : 157992, 71273, 11260563816  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution  : 10, 10  (x, y)
# extent      : 208450, 921180, 6091140, 7671060  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
# data source : //storage- al.slu.se/student$/nilc0001/Desktop/Nina/landuse/nmd2018bas_ogeneraliserad_v1_0.tif 
# names       : nmd2018bas_ogeneraliserad_v1_0 
# values      : 0, 128  (min, max)
# attributes  :
#         ID      COUNT Opacity Klass
#  from:   0 5204803484       0      
#  to  : 255          0       0   

#first few rows of attribute table of landuse
levels (landuse)   

# [[1]]
#      ID      COUNT Opacity                                              Klass
# 1     0 5204803484       0                                                   
# 2     1          0     255                                                   
# 3     2  382320369     255                                      Öppen våtmark
# 4     3  258249590     255                                           Åkermark

# crop and write csv
landuse.ekrut <- crop (landuse, ekrut)
write.csv (landuse.ekrut,"landuse.ek.csv")
```

Like I said, when I use crop and then write.csv from what I cropped I basically just get the ekrut (shapefile) as output csv file, there are no columns added of the landuse raster indicating which square has which land use class.

I would like to have a .csv which, for each square (there are 19 191 of them), gives me information on what type of landuse is present in this square.

If there is a better way to approach this, please indicate. I hope I was clear with my explanation!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your code was working, still you could not export this output into `CSV` unless you use something like `majority` filter. This is basically because of the fact that one polygon may contain more than one land-use.

One way to do this is as below:

```
library(raster)
library(stats)

#set.seed to have a reproducible example
set.seed(1523)

#making a raster layer
r <- raster(ncol=36, nrow=18, vals=floor(runif(648, 5.0, 7.5)))
rr <- aggregate(r, fact=3)
f.net <- rasterToPolygons(rr) # transform into a polygon

#simple ovelaying plot for visualisation
plot(r, main="Raster and the overlaying poly")
plot(f.net, col=rgb(1, 0, 0, alpha = 0.3), add=TRUE)
```

[image]

```
ext.r <- extract(r, f.net) # returns values per ploy

# a simple mode filter
mode <- function(x){ 
  ta = table(x)
  tam = max(ta)
  mod = as.numeric(names(ta)[ta == tam])
  mod = mod[1] 
  return(mod)
}

# each poly contains several values
head(ext.r)
# [[1]]
# [1] 6 5 5 6 5 6 5 6 5
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 5 5 6 7 6 7 6 5 7
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 5 5 7 6 6 7 6 6 7
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 6 7 5 5 7 6 5 6 5
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 5 6 5 5 5 5 6 5 5
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] 7 5 6 6 6 5 5 6 5


# a mode filter can be applied to pas majority values to each poly
mode.ext.r <- lapply(ext.r, mode)
head(mode.ext.r)
# [[1]]
# [1] 5
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 5
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 6
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 5
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 5
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] 5
write.table(mode.ext.r, file = 'mode_ext_r.csv', row.names = FALSE, na = '')
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! However, the landuse raster file is huge and my lap top got completely stuck trying to run the function rasterToPolygons... When I figure out a solution to this problem I will post it.

Comment: Why do you run `rasterToPolygons`. That is only done here to create example data.

Comment: @Nina as Rob mentioned, that is just to create example data (fishnet `f.net` similar to your shapefile gird). You already have your dataset, so you can start from the bottom patch of the script (beneath the figure). Please also consider a reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) when asking questions.

Comment: Oh, ok, my bad, I was rushing through the answer not reading throughly... I will try to run it again with more care.
@rob

Answer (score 0):

You can extract all classes for each polygon, make a table for each polygon, and then combine them.

Building off on Majid's example data.

```
library(raster)
set.seed(1523)
r <- raster(ncol=9, nrow=6, vals=sample(10, 9*6, replace=TRUE))
rr <- aggregate(raster(r), fact=3)
pols <- rasterToPolygons(rr) # transform into a polygon
plot(r); lines(pols);  text(pols, 1:length(pols))
```

Extract, create table, and combine

```
e <- extract(r, pols)
x <- lapply(e, table)
y <- lapply(1:length(x), function(i) data.frame(pol=i, as.data.frame(x[[i]])))
z <- do.call(rbind, y)

head(z, 10)
#   pol Var1 Freq
#1    1    1    2
#2    1    2    2
#3    1    3    2
#4    1    6    2
#5    1    9    1
#6    2    1    1
#7    2    2    1
#8    2    4    2
#9    2    6    2
#10   2    7    1
```

And save to csv

```
write.csv(z, "test.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution! However, same problem as above, the landuse file is huge and my lap top got stuck trying to run it...